# cascade foreign key trough multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

In my application i have the following tables:

```
projects
files
revisions
comments
project_files
file_revisions
revision_comments
```

the 3 last tables always contain 2 fields with foreign keys to the two tables (so file_revisions has a field file_id as a foreign key to files and a field revision_id foreign key to revisions)

Now if I delete a file from files the link in project_files and file_revisions is successfully deleted as the keys have CASCADE on delete but the entry in revisions for that file remain in the revisions table and therfore also the comments.

Is there a way to automate that? Or do i have to select all revisions for the file first and then remove all comments to all those revisions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your `revisions` are dependent on `files`, you shouldn't use a relationship table like `file_revisions`, you should directly have a FK in `revisions` pointing to `files`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was indeed not a good idea with the relationship table, added a FK in revisions and comments and files, so also deleting a project will cascade through the files which will cascade through the revisions and so on. If you post your comment as an answer i can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every *revision* always correspond to exactly one *file*, and should be deleted when that *file* is deleted, then having a relationship table like `file_revisions` doesn't seem a good model for your data.

You should directly have a `FK` in your `revisions` table pointing to `files`.

Likewise, `comments` can have a FK pointing to `revisions`.